Filter OLAP pivot table based on list. Receiving error when item # is not found
I am trying to filter an OLAP pivot table based on a list of items that's in a table. At first it didn't seem to work and received the "Run-time error '1004': The item could not be found in the OLAP Cube".
I started with one item # in the table and it worked. I then added 2 and 3 and it worked. On the fourth item I received the same error message, "item could not be found". Apparently is it stops filtering and errors when an item cannot be found.
Is there a way to resume on error?
Sub OLAPfilter()

Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim myR As Range

'data3 is set to the named range on another worksheet within the same workbook
Set myR = Range("Table5")

ReDim myArray(0 To myR.Cells.Count - 1)

'Populate the array
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To myR.Cells.Count - 1
myArray(i) = "\[Product\].\[Item UPC Number 13\].&\[" & myR.Cells(i + 1).Value & "\]"
Next i

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( \_
"\[Product\].\[Item UPC Number 13\].\[Item UPC Number 13\]").VisibleItemsList = myArray
End Sub

